# jsp - execute java function through onsubmit

Tags: java, jsp, forms, onsubmit

I have this jsp page -

```
<%@page import="java.text.Normalizer.Form"%>    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <legend>Create new customer</legend>
          <%!
        boolean checkForm(Form theForm)
        {
          // some checks on "theForm" .. 
          return false ; 
        }
        %>
        <form action="CreateCustomerServlet" method="GET" onsubmit=<%=checkForm() %>>
            // form's fields .. 
            <input type="submit" value="Create customer" />
        </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What I trying to do is when press on `submit` it will go to the `checkForm` function and check the form , and only if `checkForm` returned `true` it will go `CreateCustomerServlet` servlet .

But when I run on server this page and press on `submit` button I see that it's ignore from the`checkForm` and directly go to `CreateCustomerServlet` servlet .

I know that to this with javascript is very easy  .. but I want to do it with java function .

Comment: You should declare/define your method in a Java class (or in the servlet) not in the JSP. And when the form is submitted, and the servlet is invoked, the form object can be populated and passed to the method. Also, the `onsubmit` attribute is used to call Javascript function within the browser not a (server-side) Java method.

Comment: yes .. what you say about the passing to the servlet ,  I know . but it looks inefficient way if you can do that on client side  . so the best way to check the form without to send to sevlet is by javascript  , am I right  ?

Comment: You can save a roung-trip to the server by validating the form on the client-side. But I consider it safe to have the validation on the server-side too (in case Javascript fails somehow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the JSP is evaluated, it produces a static HTML page that's returned to the user.  The server won't be involved in the process again until it receives the form submission.  If you do want some server-side behavior executed from the `onsubmit` handler, you'll need to do it via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't directly call java function (which placed on server) from client side. You can move your checks logic on client side and use JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript for your requirement